# SQL Query not working inside a shell script

Tags: mysql, sql, shell, scripting, sh

I really need  help on this one...
so I'm writing this shell script which basically connects to MySQL database and fetches the data and give the output as a CSV file.

I'm able to connect to database and also able to get data from a simple query "`select * from test_table;`"

but when I try to write this query to make the give output as csv file from script it's giving an a syntax error.

QUERY> "`select * into outfile '/Path/.cvs' fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' from test_table;`"

this query is not working inside the script but it is working in MySQL database (CLI).

Really need help on this guys, if there is any way around of making output as csv file do tell me otherwise helpme out on this..

Error Msg I get is "ERROR 1064 (42000)" I know it's a syntax error but its only not working inside the script otherwise I don't how its working in mysql.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#scirpt to connect with db

master_db_user='root'
master_db_passwd='123'
master_db_port='3306'
master_db_host='localhost'
master_db_name='sagar_tb'


#Preparing script 

SQL_Query='select * INTO OUTFILE '/created_files/RESULT3.CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' from test_table;'

#MySql Command to connect to a database 

mysql -u$master_db_user -p$master_db_passwd -P$master_db_port -h$master_db_host -D$master_db_name <<EOF
$SQL_Query
EOF
echo "End of the Script"
```

Really need help here guys

thanks and regards,
Sagar Mandal

Comment: Consider sharing your scripts.

Comment: from the folder where you are executing the script is there a relative Path folder

Comment: @dassum I have attached the script as well kindly do take a look

Comment: @dash-o I'have now attached my script as well kindly do take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script tries to construct the command into SQL_Query. However, the implementation does take into account the quoting rules (you have to escape the quotes like ',')

```
SQL_Query='select * INTO OUTFILE '/created_files/RESULT3.CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' from test_table;'
```

For simple solution, just inline the SQL into the mysql command (formatted for readability). Using the Here document ('<

```
mysql ... <<EOF
select * INTO OUTFILE '/created_files/RESULT3.CSV' ...
EOF
```

Comment: can you please share more little I didn't get your point ....i didn't get your EOF part. Please Buddy need help on this one

Comment: You have the <<EOF in the current script. What kind of additional info do you need ?

Comment: so should i remove my first EOF and add my query with the creds

Comment: i tried to create only text file also but still its giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can run any query from script using below style

```
myaql -uroot -ppassword -hlocalhost -e 'SELECT * FROM database.table_name';
```

I have edited my reply according to your script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#scirpt to connect with db

master_db_user='root'
master_db_passwd='123'
master_db_port='3306'
master_db_host='localhost'
master_db_name='sagar_tb'


#Preparing script 

SQL_Query='select * INTO OUTFILE '/created_files/RESULT3.CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' from test_table;'

#MySql Command to connect to a database 

mysql -u$master_db_user -p$master_db_passwd -P$master_db_port -h$master_db_host -D$master_db_name -e '$SQL_Query';
echo "End of the Script"
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/bash

#scirpt to connect with db

master_db_user='root'
master_db_passwd='123'
master_db_port='3306'
master_db_host='localhost'
master_db_name='sagar_tb'



mysql -u$master_db_user -p$master_db_passwd -P$master_db_port -h$master_db_host -D$master_db_name select * INTO OUTFILE '/created_files/RESULT3.CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' from test_table; <<EOF
$SQL_Query
EOF
echo "End of the Script"

Comment: hey man I tried your method but its still showing me the above error